# How to make chart fonts in italics? (ggplot2 and factoextra package)

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a graph with `fviz_pca_ind()` function where the words for each point are included in italics. I managed to leave the names of the axes, numbers of the axes and legends, however, I cannot find an alternative to the words that are inside the graph. I can't find anything to that effect either in the ggplot2 package or in the factoextra package. So I hope you can help me, follow the code and image below.

```
# creating data table
lines <- c(1,2,3,55,56,57,120,121,122,123,124)
df <- iris[lines,]
.rowNamesDF(df, make.names=TRUE) <- rep("specie_name", 15)

# calculating pca
library(FactoMineR)
pca <- PCA(df[,1:4], graph = FALSE)

# Plotting PCA
library(factoextra)
fviz_pca_ind(pca, label = "all", habillage = as.factor(df$Species), mean.point = FALSE) +
  ylim(-2,2) + 
  xlim(-4,4) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme() +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(face="italic"),
        axis.title.x = element_text(face="italic"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(face="italic"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(face="italic"),
        legend.text = element_text(face="italic")
        ) +
  ggsave("pca.png", width = 15, height = 10, units = "cm", dpi=300)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular case, you can set the fontface of layer 2 to italic:

```r
lines <- c(1,2,3,55,56,57,120,121,122,123,124)
df <- iris[lines,]
.rowNamesDF(df, make.names=TRUE) <- rep("specie_name", 15)
library(FactoMineR)
pca <- PCA(df[,1:4], graph = FALSE)
library(factoextra)
pv <- fviz_pca_ind(pca, label = "all", habillage = as.factor(df$Species), 
                   mean.point = FALSE) +
    ylim(-2,2) + 
    xlim(-4,4) +
    theme_classic()+
    theme(text = element_text(face="italic"),
          title = element_text(face="italic"),
          plot.caption=element_text(face="italic"),
          plot.tag=element_text(face="italic")
    )
pv$layers[[2]]$aes_params$fontface <- "italic"
pv
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: His answer worked perfectly, user12728748 . I had a similar post but using a dendrogram. It worked perfectly too. Follow the post link: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61602871/how-to-put-italic-font-in-dendrogram-using-factoextra-package)